# Does this O(n) sorting method already exist?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The idea is to set all values to their parent index in the final array and then remove all null values.
Here is some simple implementation:

```
int x[] = {9,3,4,2,1,12,5};
sortList(x)

public static int[] sortList(int[] x){
    int[] y = new int[15];
    for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
        int value = x[i];
        y[value] = value;
    }
    return removeNull(y);
}
public static int[] removeNull(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i != 0).toArray();
}
```

As a note, it only sorts unique non zero values. This is what the method is doing when going through an array:

The array -> 9,3,4,2,1,5 will be converted to -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,9,0,0 and then to -> 1,2,3,4,5,9
If I am corret this solution would loop through the array 3 times and take y size as it's storage. Does this sorting method already exist?

Comment: What happened to the 12? It looks like it only loops through the original array one time. Seems the code should do an initial pass through x to determine the minimum and maximum values, which could be used to set the range and size of y[]. You might want to add a java tag since that appears to be what the code is based on. This method is similar to counting sort, except that it's limited to only work with unique values (0 or 1 instance of values in the range for minimum to maximum values in x[]).

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, I have already dealt with min and max values, I just did not post it as it would make the algorithm a bit more complex. Are you saying that this will not work? Wouldn't this be a more efficient solution to many sorting problems than counting sort if all values are unique?

Comment: @joshLor: and what do you do if one value is 4.3872*10^342 or if the values are strings? This is much to restricted to deserve the name sorting algorithm.

Comment: Generic sorting algorithms have to work on arbitrary inputs, not all of which will be unique or numbers.

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm is not O(n). Sorting the array (x^2, x) with this algorithm takes a number of operations that depends on x. But a O(n) algorithm that could sort such an array made of 2 values should take a maximum number of operation depending on the size (2) of the array, so it should have an upper bound. So it shoud not depend on the arbitral value of x.

Comment: @joshLor - If all values are unique, then counting sort can be sped up by storing 1's (or any non-zero value) instead of incrementing. For example, the code would be `count[value] = 1` instead of `count[value] = count[value] + 1`, and count[] could be an array of bytes (or booleans) instead of an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is known as [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Here's Wikipedia's description:

> In computer science, counting sort is an algorithm for sorting a collection of objects according to keys that are small integers; that is, it is an integer sorting algorithm. It operates by counting the number of objects that have each distinct key value, and using arithmetic on those counts to determine the positions of each key value in the output sequence. Its running time is linear in the number of items and the difference between the maximum and minimum key values, so it is only suitable for direct use in situations where the variation in keys is not significantly greater than the number of items.

As you point out, your algorithm discards duplicates. Counting sort gets its name by its solution to this problem: counting the number of items of each key. This algorithm is indeed linear, but the high constant factor in both time and space means its rarely used in practice.